# Counting Items in a field to condense in a table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

```
SELECT [Import].[Product Name 1], Sum([Import].[Product 1 Qty]) AS [SumOfProduct 1 Qty]
FROM [Import]
GROUP BY [Import].[Product Name 1];
```

I have this and it is working like I need. I now need it to do the same thing for Products and Qtys 2 - 10. The catch is I want it to add to the totals from the first one and not make a new column in my table. I need this to generate a report and an export for billing and shipping.

I am importing data from a client with customer information. It has all the required shipping info as well as the product we are supposed to ship and quantity per customer. Each customer can have up to 10 items with varying quantities. My goal is to generate this report with the only purpose of showing the item and the amount of the item needed to pull from stock. We will be using this report as a "pick ticket" in our fulfillment department. It will also be used for billing purposes to out client. The reason I want the Items and Qty in a table is for an export back to the client. The only 2 columns I want in the table are the product and the total number of that product ordered.

Comment: Could you give the schema definition of your table and sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this with `union all`:

```
SELECT [Import].[Product Name], Sum([Import].[Product 1 Qty]) AS [SumOfProduct Qty]
FROM [Import]
GROUP BY [Import].[Product Name 1]
union all
SELECT [Import].[Product Name 2], Sum([Import].[Product 2 Qty]) AS [SumOfProduct Qty]
FROM [Import]
GROUP BY [Import].[Product Name 2]
union all
...
SELECT [Import].[Product Name 10], Sum([Import].[Product 10 Qty]) AS [SumOfProduct Qty]
FROM [Import]
GROUP BY [Import].[Product Name 10];
```

This assumes that the products are different in each column.  If the products are the same and you want the total:

```
SELECT ProductName, sum(ProductQTY)
FROM (select [Product Name 1] as ProductName, [Product 1 Qty] as ProductQty
      from [Import] union all
      select [Product Name 2], [Product 2 Qty]
      from [Import] union all
      . . .
      select [Product Name 10], [Product 10 Qty]
      from [Import]
     ) i
GROUP BY ProductName;
```

The `...` in both cases means that you put in similar code for the rest of the products, not the literal "...".

Comment: If they can be the same or different would the first one still work?

Comment: @Chuck . . . The first version puts the count for each column in a separate row.  So, a product might appear up to 10 times.  The second combines them into one row.

Comment: I am having an issue..... I have the same product for 2 different customers. Lets say CustomerA gets a postcard and a pin. CustomerB get a magnet and a postcard. now the postcard is in column 1 and 2 so it is showing me 2 counts of the postcard with 1 in each. Right count but is making the report enormous for my db. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Chuck . . . Can you ask another question with sample data and expected results?